# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para quitar la action bar en una Activity especifica?

Tags: android-studio

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/slpashflag">



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

El problema es que quiero quitar la ActionBar de mi SplashActivity pero en el resto de las pantallas quiero conservarla. Solo quiero quitarla de esa Activity

Comment: pon el codigo de tu splash, ya que un splashScreen por lo general solo es un xml

Comment: Lo único que tiene es una imagen de fondo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma es agregar este código en `onCreate` de tu Activity:

```
ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.hide();
```

Otra forma es asignandole un style dentro del `Manifest`:

```
<activity
        android:name=".TuActivity"
        android:label="@string/tu_activity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"/>
```

Aquí estas asignando un tema, en este caso llamado Theme.Transparent. En
Style ese tema sería así:

```
 <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```